# Order of DOM NodeList returned by getChildNodes()

Tags: java, xml, dom

The DOM method `getChildNodes()` returns a `NodeList` of the children of the current `Node`. Whilst a `NodeList` is ordered, is the list guaranteed to be in document order?

For example, given `<a><b/><c/><d/></a>` is `a.getChildNodes()` guaranteed to return a `NodeList` with `b`, `c` and `d` *in that order*?

The [javadoc](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#getChildNodes()) isn't clear on this.

Comment: This question is probably relevant to other programming languages, but I am specifically wondering about Java (*not* Javascript).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my experience, yes. The [DOM spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-DOM-Level-2-Core-20001113/core.html#ID-1451460987) isn't any clearer. If you're paranoid, try something like

```
current = node.firstChild;
while(null != current) {
    ...
    current = current.nextSibling;
}
```

Comment: I'm curious... Why do you write `null != foo` instead of `foo != null`? Is that a Java thing? :)

Comment: @Šime Vidas I think it's actually a C thing, but with Java's C syntax it seemed wise. The idea is that if you make a typo and write 'null = x' when you meant 'null == x', the compiler will complain. 'x = null' being valid, even in a if test statement. And you should then do the same with the other operators for consistence's sake.

Comment: Aha, not a bad idea. Another mechanism is to put your code trough JSLint which will alert on assignments in if headers and other places where assignments are unusual.

Comment: Eclipse has a warning for that too. I would prefer writing ´foo == null´ because it's more natural to read.

Answer (score 2):

A document-ordered node list is the behavior in other implementations of the DOM, such as Javascript's or Python's. And a randomly-ordered node list would be utterly useless. I think it's safe to depend on nodes being returned in document order.

Answer (score 2):

My experience is that every time that I have bothered to look it has been in document order. However, I believe that I read somewhere it is not guaranteed to be in document order. I can't find where I read that right now, so take it as hearsay. I think your best bet if you **must** have them in document order would be to use FirstChild then NextSibling until there are no more sibs.

Comment: I seem to as well; it's surprising how quickly people jump on these questions here!

Comment: Yes, but no-one has been able to answer it definitively!

Let me know if you find that reference.

Answer (score 0):

I'd love to tell you that this is guaranteed (as I believe it is) but the [Document Object Model specification](http://www.w3.org/DOM/) itself seems ambiguous in this case. I'm pretty sure that it's always document-order, though.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, as presented. I believe so. However, I've experienced real-world experiences where spaces have been interpreted as nodes so:

```
<a><b/><c/><d/></a>
```

is different than

```
<a><b/> <c/><d/></a>
```

if you're looking at index [1], firefox and IE may present different results. I would advise against relying on the order depending on your need.

Comment: Well, it is different; there's a text node in the middle!

Answer (score 0):

Yes they are ordered as it returns a nodeList, you would have to say getNamedChildNodes to get a list that is not ordered as in namedNodeList.

Comment: I don't think you read the question properly. A NodeList is always ordered (regardless of which method returns it). However, is it guaranteed to be in *Document* order?