# Should I use the position of XML elements to detemine their order?

Tags: xml

Say I've got a snippet of XML

```
<Items>
  <SubItem Name="Banana">
  <SubItem Name="Apple">
<Items>
```

Is it valid to say that Banana comes before Apple? I know it does syntactically - but does it semantically.

Or do I need to include some ordering attribute:

```
<Items>
  <SubItem Name="Banana" Index="0">
  <SubItem Name="Apple" Index="1">
<Items>
```

Comment: You can have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/66032/order-of-dom-nodelist-returned-by-getchildnodes that is complementary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is something in XML (XPath, really) called ["document order"](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath#dt-document-order). So yes, document order is a valid thing you can rely on.

It can change only if the document changes. No "ordering attribute" needed unless you cannot guarantee that the document is being *built* in the right order.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can generally rely on the order of elements in your document. XML processing tools *should* respect it when they transform and parse your document. It would probably still be a good idea to check.

Note, BTW, that *attribute order* (order of attributes inside an element) is not guaranteed by the standard.